# Why don't I get a comment button on people's questions and answers?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Most of the time I don't get a comment button on people's questions and answers. Is there a reason? Or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: you need 50 rep to comment - see http://stackoverflow.com/faq (Link at the top of the page)

Comment: ...and lo and behold ;) Try commenting now!

Answer (score 1):

You need 50 points to comment other people's posts.

https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: You need to expand the "What is reputation?" section to see the information about 50 rep points being needed to comment on other people's posts.  I believe if you use http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation then that section will be expanded automatically.

Answer (score 0):

See the SO FAQ.  You need a reputation of 50 or more to leave comments on others questions and answers.  Keep plugging away, it will surely come.

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment:

> Please note that you can always comment on your own posts, and any part of your questions. However, commenting on other people's posts is a privilege.

That page indicates that you need 50 reputation points to be able to comment on other people's posts.

The relevant part of the SO FAQ is at https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation.